# Size of PDF files generated by knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I am using the following chunk in an `Rnw` file.

```
<<scatter,dev='pdf',include=TRUE>>=
a <- rnorm(1e4)
b <- rnorm(1e4)
plot(a,b)
@
```

I knitted the same `Rnw` file under `R3.6.3` and `R4.0.2`, respectively. However, the PDF figure generated under `R4.0.2` is much larger (~8 times) than the one from `R3.6.3`.

I am wondering if there is a way (eg. a chunk option) to reduce the PDF size under `R4.0.2`.

The session information of two different versions of R is shown below.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.29

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 magrittr_1.5   tools_4.0.2    stringi_1.4.6  highr_0.8      stringr_1.4.0 
[7] xfun_0.16      evaluate_0.14
```

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.28

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 magrittr_1.5   tools_3.6.3    stringi_1.4.6  highr_0.8      stringr_1.4.0 
[7] xfun_0.12      evaluate_0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reference to pdf in the [release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) lately has been in relation to the dingbats font. Looking at the reference, it says (emphasis mine):

> useDingbats    logical. Should small circles be rendered via the
> Dingbats font? Defaults to TRUE, which produces **smaller** and better
> output. Setting this to FALSE can work around font display problems in
> broken PDF viewers: although this font is one of the 14 guaranteed to
> be available in all PDF viewers, that guarantee is not always
> honoured.

You can change the default via

```r
pdf.options(useDingbats = TRUE)
```

in the first code chunk of your Rnw document. This change is global to your document. If you'd rather change it only for a specific code chunk, you may use the chunk option `dev.args`, e.g.,

```
<<scatter, dev='pdf', dev.args=list(useDingbats = TRUE)>>=
a <- rnorm(1e4)
b <- rnorm(1e4)
plot(a,b)
@
```